# How to handle the errors while data migration to cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark-sql, datastax

trying to migrate the data from oracle to cassandra i have below issues:

How to handle the errors while data migration to cassandra using spark-sql?
How to design the retry machanisum if anything fails ?
Is there any document/sample/github regarding the same.

~Sha

Comment: This question does not seem answerable because it lacks both context and specificity.  Try asking it with some specific cases, or architectural descriptions.

Comment: @pfranza, i am trying to design a utility migrate the data from oracle db to cassandra using spark-sql . if the data retrieved from oracle in a dataframe. while inserting into cassandra if it fails how to handle these errors , how to retry again , in such a way we should query the oracle again , do i require any staging area ? if so where should store? if there is any error happens while loading to cassandra , how to design it in such a way it would be easily understandable so that it can be retry from where it failed/error last time , instead of reading it from oracle again. how to design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can look into these below github repos for reference
https://github.com/snazy/Oracle_to_Cassandra
https://github.com/AlexGruPerm/oratocass

Comment: sir thank you so much really wounderful. Sir can you explain the ID_POK :Int, ID_OIV :Long     in the below  '   case class T_DATA_STATS(TABLE_NAME :String, DDATE: Int, ID_POK :Int, ID_OIV :Long, ROW_COUNT :Long, INSERT_DUR_MS :Double) '

Comment: what is the mechanism you are following for Error handling if there is any , how are you tracking ? If there is any node failures/ network issues what are you following as retry mechanism ? Does this handle millions of data ? Why there is no E/T/L sections ? if we want to provide how to segregate the code ? any books or blogs which can help me... please

Comment: I have gone through above AlexGruPerm git , there data frames read from oracle are processed and storing in CassandraDB , there is no mechanism of Failure handling and Error logging ? how to handle the same ?